# Extending the annotation __Dymola_Commands

Tags: modelica, dymola

For testing my models, I have created a base class (let's call it `TBbase_goingForABeer`) to be extended (the testbenches will be then `TB_foot`, `TB_bike`, and `TB_bus`). Eventually, I might want to plot the same signals every time I go out for a beer.

If I create a script to plot the results and add it as a command to the base class `TBbase_goingForABeer`, such command does not show up in the testbenches extending it.

Is there a way to control the inheritance of specific annotations, in this particular case the vendor annotation __Dymola_Commands? Perhaps through one of the many Dymola flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That specific annotation can be inherited by using inherit=true as follows:

```
__Dymola_Commands(file(inherit=true, ensureSimulated=true) = "scriptName.mos" "Description")
```

(And similarly for other variants.) It is somewhat supported in the GUI, but it seems it should be enabled in more cases.